# About inequality $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 \lessgtr \sum_{k\neq s} |a_k| |a_s|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a_k$ a sequence of complex number. We have
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|\right)^2 \geq \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2$$
It is a basic fact because
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 + \sum_{k\neq s} |a_k| |a_s|$$
Mine is a curiosity, and not a real question. What we know to say about the following inequality?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 \lessgtr \sum_{k\neq s} |a_k| |a_s|$$
Is it always true ($<$ or $>$), in one of two directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add $\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2$ to both sides, we get

$$2\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2 \lessgtr \Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert\Biggr)^2.$$

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says

$$\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert\Biggr)^2 \leqslant n\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2,$$

and the inequality is sharp, i.e. we can have equality (when all $\lvert a_k\rvert$ are equal).

Thus for $n = 1$ or $n = 2$ we always have the non-strict inequality

$$\sum_{k\neq s} \lvert a_k\rvert\cdot \lvert a_s\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2,$$

and for $n = 1$, the inequality is strict unless $a_1 = 0$, while for $n = 2$ the inequality is strict unless $\lvert a_1\rvert = \lvert a_2\rvert$.

For $n \geqslant 3$, there always are sequences such that

$$\sum_{k\neq s} \lvert a_k\rvert\cdot\lvert a_s\rvert > \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2,\tag{1}$$

and sequences such that

$$\sum_{k\neq s} \lvert a_k\rvert\cdot\lvert a_s\rvert < \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert^2.\tag{2}$$

Case $(1)$ is achieved for example when all $\lvert a_k\rvert$ are equal, and by continuity also when they are close enough to each other. Case $(2)$ is achieved for example when one of the $\lvert a_k\rvert$ is large, and the others are all very small. Say $\lvert a_1\rvert = 1$ and $\lvert a_k\rvert = \frac{1}{n^3}$ for $2 \leqslant k \leqslant n$.